# Invert Map <String, List<String>> using Java 8 streams

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I need to invert a map which is `<String, List<String>>` to `Map<String,String>` using Java 8, with the assumption that the values are unique. For example,

Input map -

```
{"Fruit" -> ["apple","orange"], "Animal" -> ["Dog","Cat"]}
```

Output map

```
{"apple" -> "Fruit", "orange" -> "Fruit", "Dog"->"Animal", "Cat" -> "Animal"}
```

```java
Map <String, String> outputMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : inputMap.entrySet()) {
    entry.getValue().forEach(value -> outputMap.put(value, entry.getKey()));
}
```

Is this right? Can we achieve this using streams Java 8?

Comment: you can, but it's not going to be pretty: `inputMap.stream().flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().stream().map(singleValue -> new SimpleEntry(entry.getKey(), singleValue)).collect(toMap(entry::getValue, entry::getKey));`

Comment: Correction to the above as per your requirement would be `inputMap.entrySet().stream()
                .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().stream().map(singleValue -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(singleValue, entry.getKey())))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getValue, Map.Entry::getKey));` or alternatively `Map<String, String> outputMap = new HashMap<>();
        inputMap.forEach((key, value1) -> value1.forEach(value -> outputMap.put(value, key)));` given the uniqueness of the keys.

Comment: IMO non-stream version looks more readable in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You an try this way

```
Map <String, String> updatedMap = new HashMap<>();
oldMap.keySet()
      .forEach(i -> oldMap.get(i)
                          .forEach(k -> updatedMap.put(k, i)));
```

Comment: A simpler equivalent: `oldMap.forEach((k, v) -> v.forEach(v2 -> updatedMap.put(v2, k)));`

Answer (score 1):

Do like this :

```
public class InverterMap {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, List<String>> mp = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        mp.put("Fruit", Arrays.asList("Apple", "Orange"));
        mp.put("Animal", Arrays.asList("Dog", "Cat"));
        System.out.println(mp);  // It returned {Fruit=[Apple, Orange], Animal=[Dog, Cat]}

        Map<String, String> invertMap = mp.entrySet().stream().collect(HashMap::new,
            (m, v) -> v.getValue().forEach(k -> m.put(k, v.getKey())), Map::putAll);

        System.out.println(invertMap);// It returned {Apple=Fruit, Cat=Animal, Orange=Fruit, Dog=Animal}

    }

}
```

Read [Stream.collect(Supplier supplier, BiConsumer, BiConsumer combiner)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

```java
Map<String, String> outputMap = inputMap.entrySet().stream()
        .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().map(v -> Map.entry(e.getKey(), v)))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getValue, Map.Entry::getKey));
```

## Step-by-step breakdown

1. Convert the map to a stream of entries.

   ```java
   // Stream<Map.Entry<String, List<String>>>
   inputMap.entrySet().stream()
   ```
2. Split apart each entry into a separate item per item in the value list.

   ```java
   // Stream<Map.Entry<String, String>>
   .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().map(v -> Map.entry(e.getKey(), v)))
   ```
3. Convert the entries to a new map, with keys equal to the previous values, and values equal to the previous keys.

   ```java
   // Map<String, String>
   .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getValue, Map.Entry::getKey));
   ```